# Boundary Event on User Task in Activiti not triggerred

Tags: java, activiti, business-process-management

I am using Activiti BPM to implement a simple workflow. This workflow sends email to users and awaits user feedback. If feedback is not received for 24 hrs, it will again send the email and await for response.

I used boundary event like this:

```
      <boundaryEvent id="boundarytimer1" name="Timer" attachedToRef="userTask" cancelActivity="true">
    <timerEventDefinition>
      <timeDuration>PT24H</timeDuration>
    </timerEventDefinition>
  </boundaryEvent>
```

I can see timer job created in ACT_RU_JOB table. However this job is not triggerred.

Comment: What happened after timer has exceeded? Job still exists after 24h hours? Do you have any outer flow from boundary event?

Comment: @Peter - Job still exists after 24h. There is an outer flow from boundary event to send email system task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you didn't set `jobExecutorActivate=true` inside your Activiti configuration.

```
<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
        <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="true" />
        <property name="history" value="activity"/>
</bean>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's absolutely spot on Petar. I added this property and it's working now! Thanks Petar.

Answer (score 0):

```
From activiti 6.0.0 Version 
need to use springConfiguration.setAsyncExecutorActivate(true);
<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.spring.SpringProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
        <property name="databaseSchemaUpdate" value="true" />
        <property name="asyncExecutorActivate" value="true" />
        <property name="history" value="activity"/>
</bean>
```

Comment: Could you add explanation to what this does and how it answers the question.